# bash: why "for" have different behavior when reading an array "${files[@]}"

Tags: bash

I want to read a text file line by line, here are two methods:

this method work fine, and read the text line by line, I know it using the `read` command

```
readarray -t files < c.txt

for i in "${files[@]}"; do  
    printf '%s\n' "$i" >> 2.txt
    read -p 'press enter to continue'
done
```

but this method read all the file in one time and not line by line!

```
for i in "$(<c.txt)"; do 
    printf '%s\n' "$i" >> 1.txt
    read -p 'press enter to continue'
done
```

if I remove the double quotes in `"$(<c.txt)"` and use  `IFS=$'\n'` and `set -f` it read the text line by line as expected.

**the question:**
why when I used `"${files[@]}"` it reads line by line , why `for` have different behavior?

text file used in this exemples:

```
$ cat c.txt

this   is         a   test   
)=_ç)çà)èç(-è_-'é²"²2°4.²&é (§/%Mµ%µ¨£¨P£

    trailing space        



tab                
#comment
*
echo test
```

Comment: `"$(<c.txt)"` gets full file content in a string. You should be using: `while IFS= read -r; do echo "$line"; done < file`

Comment: `readarray` reads line by line into an array. That's it's job. Your second example has nothing that reads line by line, only something that reads an entire file.

Comment: @anubhava yes I know but I don' t like the `read` method because of the ffmpeg,ssh..ect problem [link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) so I dont like to use it because I don t know what behavior will have with all the linux world commands. the strange thing is why `"${files[@]}"` read line by line!?

Comment: That is the intended behavior of array. `"${files[*]}"` will read all of it in single iteration.

Comment: I am not sure, 'I don't like it cause it does blah' is really a good argument.  You have chosen to use bash (and have plenty of other options) so you have to work within its limitations.  Why not just always use the -u option whether using a command that eats all the information or not?  It really is a very small change to make, so that your loop always works.

Comment: @grail Thank you, but I m working in cygwin and when I tested the file descriptor FD I had a lot of errors that I did not know how to solve. And reading @StéphaneChazelas post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) convinced me to leave the `read` method and search for an alternative, which is `readarray` that seems to work very well, is there any thing I have to know to prefer read over readarray? because bash 4 is old now and you find readarray everywhere. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using `for` is that it doesn't know anything about lines -- `for` expects to be given a list of "words" to iterate over. If you use `for i in "$(<c.txt)"`, the double-quotes tell the shell not to do any parsing on the contents of the file, so the entire contents will be treated as a single word. On the other hand, if you leave off the double-quotes (`for i in $(<c.txt)`), the shell will split the file's contents into "words" separated by whitespace (by default that means spaces, tabs, and newlines), and then tries to expand any of those words that include wildcards into a list of matching filenames. You can adjust the shell options to make this split-and-expand process work more like what you want, but fundamentally it's meant for doing something else and at best it'll be a kluge.

If you want to read lines from a file, use something that's meant for reading lines from a file. `read` and `readarray` are both intended for this purpose. The have their own quirks and such that you may need to work around, but they at least start in the right area; `for` really doesn't. BTW, the [BashFAQ entry you linked](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089) has a perfectly good workaround for the problem with ffmpeg etc:

```
while read -r line <&3; do
    ...
done 3<file
```

The `readline` approach you gave will also work fine, but isn't as portable. What `readline` does is read the entire file into a shell array, with each line as a separate array element. Then `"${files[@]}"` tells the shell to expand the array contents, *with each array element treated as a separate word*. Thus lines become array elements, which become "words", which are the things `for` iterates over, and you get your expected result.

Comment: ah, so `${files[@]}` is the responsible and not the `for`. Your sentence "**_each array element treated as a separate word_**" explained a little what happen there. thank you very much